# Time Series Forecasting in Tensorflow 2.0 - How to predict using the last of the Validation Dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm (desperately) trying to figure out Tensorflow 2.0 without much luck so far, but I think I'm close with what I need right now.

I've followed [the doc here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#multi-step_model) to make a simple network to forecast stock data (not weather data), and what I'd like to do now is, forecast the future using the latest/most recent section of the validation dataset. I'm hoping someone else has read through it already and can help me here.

The code to predict the future using the validation dataset looks like this:

```
for x, y in val_data_multi.take(3):
  multi_step_plot(x[0], y[0], multi_step_model.predict(x)[0])
```

...where to the best of my knowledge, it takes a random chunk (3 separate times), and in my case is a 20 row x 9 column section, from the `val_data_multi` "Repeat dataset" type, and then uses the model's `multi_step_plot` function to spit out a plot that has the predicted values based on that random section of the validation dataset. But what if I don't want to just take a random validation section, I want to use the bottom of my actual dataset? So that if I have recent stock data at the bottom of my validation dataset, and I want to forecast for the future that hasn't happened yet, how can I take a 20x9 section from the bottom of that set, and not just have it "take" a random section to predict with?

As a pseudo code attempt to explain what I'm trying to do, I was trying something like:

```
for x, y in val_data_multi[-20:].take(1): #.take(3)
```

...to try and make it take one section 20 rows up from the bottom, and all columns. But of course this didn't work as `TypeError: 'RepeatDataset' object is not subscriptable`.

I hope that makes sense, and if it'll help for me to post my code, I can do that, but I'm just using what's already shown in that page, just made some modifications to use a stock dataset, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a much better guide from this Github repo:

https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/23_Time-Series-Prediction.ipynb

...which basically gets into better detail what I'm looking to do and made it very easy to understand. Thanks!